# How to properly define REST resources in kottpd

Tags: rest, kotlin, url, resources

I'm working on a REST-Server in Kotlin using [kottpd](https://github.com/gimlet2/kottpd)

Here's an excerpt of the resources / URIs I've defined:

```
get("/patients") {req, res -> PatientHandler.doGetAll(req, res)}
post("/patients") {req, res -> PatientHandler.doPost(req, res)}

get("/patients/.*") {req, res -> PatientHandler.doGetOne(req, res)}
post("/patients/.*") {req, res -> PatientHandler.doPatch(req, res)}

get("/patients/.*/cases") {req, res -> CaseHandler.doGetAll(req, res)}
post("/patients/.*/cases") {req, res -> CaseHandler.doPost(req, res)}
```

`/patients` and `/patients/.*` have been working fine so far: e.g.
`POST: /patients` adds a patient to the list and `GET: /patients/1` retrieves the patient with ID 1.

However, when calling `POST: /patients/1/cases` to add a case to patient 1, the functions attached to `POST: /patients/.*` are executed.

I assume(!) that `.*` is a wildcard and thus there's no distinction between there being an ID, some more path or just whatever.

How can I define my resources / URIs to distinguish between these cases?
Or, in case my assumptions isn't correct: what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to replace `.*` with `\d+`,

eg. `GET: /patients/\d+/cases`
or `get("/patients/\\d+/cases")`

As pointed out by u/8bitlives on reddit:

> https://github.com/gimlet2/kottpd/blob/master/src/main/kotlin/com/github/gimlet2/kottpd/Server.kt#L128
>
> Seems like the paths are used as pure regex patterns. So .* is "anything 0 or more times". Replacing the wildcard with a more precise \d+ meaning "one or more numbers". I'd suggest writing the paths avoidin the wildcard altogether. And using a service like regex101.com to validate the patterns.